# How can I produce a document with Gujarati language in LaTeX?

Tags: languages, indic

I have tried the `itrans` package, but was unsuccessful to achieve producing document with indian language (especially gujarati). The documentation of `itrans` is not clear, at least to me.

Can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: This is very, very open ended; Could you specify exactly what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Have you tried XeTeX support of Unicode? I was having no trouble with XeTeX and CJK, and, I think, you won't have troubles with gujarati also.

Comment: As it stands, this is 'Not A Real Question' as it's very open. If it can be made a bit more focussed then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any ttf font in TeX using xetex. First you download and install any gujarathi font (for example -- [Saumil_guj2](http://saumil.net/howto/gujfont/gujfont.html), here you will find instructions on how to type those fonts also, check the bottom of the page).

Then write a tex file like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode,fixltx2e}
  \usepackage{xltxtra}
%  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % To support LaTeX quoting style
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Saumil_guj2}
  %\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{mathpazo}
\fi
\begin{document}
\section{Unicode support}

\subsection{English}
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. All
human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.

maaro gau J ra tal saaOimala

\end{document}
```

Compile this with xelatex.

[image]

Comment: Hello sir, i am not able to compile the codes. getting some errors.

Comment: Getting errors while compliling.